# Chrome bugging height property again

Tags: css, google-chrome, height

Okay, so I've been practicing yesterday and after a few hours I checked this in Chrome (was working with firefox). How should i fix that?
I don't know where does it take the ridiculous height from.

Here's the preview i get (left is firefox, right is chrome)
[image]

Styling:

```
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #f0ca4d;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      font-family: "Roboto";
      color: white;
    }
    .popup {
      margin-top: 100px;
      width: 400px;
/*      height: 300px;*/
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(51,51,51,0.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(51,51,51,0.2);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(51,51,51,0.2);
      position: relative;

    }
    .top {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70px;
      background-color: #324d5c;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .top span {
      margin: 32px 16px 16px 16px;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    .content {
      color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      margin: 32px 32px 0px 32px;
      line-height: 150%;
    }
    .fab {
      width: 48px;
      height: 48px;
      background-color: #de5b49;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: 16px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top: 46px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .fab:hover span {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fab span {
      font-size: 30px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 48px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .bot span {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #324d5c;
      font-weight: 500;
      padding: 16px 32px 16px 32px;

      transition: background-color 0.45s cubic-bezier(0,1,.83,.67) 0.08s;
      background-color: white;
    }
    .bot span:hover {
      background-color: #f8f8f8;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .bot {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    #disabled {
      color: #d1d1d1;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    #disabled:hover {
      background-color: white !important;
      cursor: default;
      -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
      -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
      -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
      user-select: none;          /* Likely future */
    }
```

Sctructure:

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="top">
        <span>Warning box</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fab">
      <span>+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<!--       <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <span id="disabled">disabled</span>
      <span>ENABLED</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can't get this to work.

Comment: I ran this on live preview of brackets on chrome and it is giving me the same output as the left side image of your question which is the square box..

Comment: Well that's odd, it's going through brackets to chrome for me too

Comment: Yep, i sent it to a friend, he has the same issue as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have in chrome..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title> Stack Overflow issues</title>
    <style>



       html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f0ca4d;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            font-family: "Roboto";
            color: white;
        }

        .popup {
            margin-top: 100px;
            width: 400px;
            /*      height: 300px;*/
            background-color: #fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
            position: relative;
        }

        .top {
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: #324d5c;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            ;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .top span {
            margin: 32px 16px 16px 16px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        .content {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            margin: 32px 32px 0px 32px;
            line-height: 150%;
        }

        .fab {
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            background-color: #de5b49;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: 16px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top: 46px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .fab:hover span {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .fab span {
            font-size: 30px;
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 48px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .bot span {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #324d5c;
            font-weight: 500;
            padding: 16px 32px 16px 32px;
            transition: background-color 0.45s cubic-bezier(0, 1, .83, .67) 0.08s;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .bot span:hover {
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .bot {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        #disabled {
            color: #d1d1d1;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        #disabled:hover {
            background-color: white !important;
            cursor: default;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            /* Chrome all / Safari all */
            -moz-user-select: none;
            /* Firefox all */
            -ms-user-select: none;
            /* IE 10+ */
            user-select: none;
            /* Likely future */
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="popup">
        <div class="top">
            <span>Warning box</span>
        </div>
        <div class="fab">
            <span>+</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <!--       <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> -->
        </div>
        <div class="bot">
            <span id="disabled">disabled</span>
            <span>ENABLED</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks bud,
got it sorted out now.

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` is crucial for chrome, but it didn't change anything within firefox.

As it was just a small element i forgot to put it in

Comment: I too learned something that i didn't know..thanks for mentioning this..will keep this mind for future also..take care and god bless